# Не работает замена слов в буфере

Tags: c#, winforms

Слова в буфере не заменяются, как исправить код, чтоб все работало?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Words
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> words = new List<string>
        {
            "планета",
            "космос",
            "вселенная",
        };

        public Form1()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string buffer = Clipboard.GetText().Trim();
                if (buffer.Contains(" "))
                    Console.Write("Этот текст не подходит");
                else
                    for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string word = words[i];
                        if (buffer.Substring(0, 3) == word.Substring(0, 3) && buffer.Substring(buffer.Length - 3) == word.Substring(word.Length - 3))
                        {
                            Clipboard.SetText(word);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: мало что понятно из вашего вопроса и кода, опишите задачу подробнее, приведите пример корректной работы

Comment: Так у вас форма даже не отрисовывается, наверное? Вы что хотите - чтобы в фоне эта работа делалась или где или как? В конструкторе формы такое написать если, то форма просто не отрисуется. Написать в любой обработке события такой цикл - форма будет висеть и ни на что не реагировать. Это тогда фоновый какой-то процесс должен быть, или асинхронный по какому-то событию или ещё как-то как, чтобы не вешать `GUI` и не мешать ему работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы повесили приложение этим циклом и оно не способно взаимодействовать с Windows. То есть единственный поток формы, который мог бы отправить и получить содержимое буфера обмена, занят на 100% выполнением кода в вашем бесконечном цикле. Обновление буфера это не только запись в него данных, а ещё отправка сообщения об этом всем приложениям. Так вот, последнее вы и не даёте форме выполнить, и приложение, в котором вы работаете с буфером руками, например блокнот, просто не знает что буфер изменён, поэтому не забирает свежие данные, и вам кажется, что буфер не изменился.

*Никогда не пишите свой код в конструкторе формы до тех пор, пока не поймёте, какой именно код надо писать там, а какой лучше не надо. Для выполнения кода при загрузке формы есть обработчик события `Form.Load`.*

Если ничего не менять в приложении, но разморозить ему работу с операционной системой, то код будет выглядеть так.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<string> words = new List<string>
    {
        "планета",
        "космос",
        "вселенная",
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string buffer = Clipboard.GetText().Trim();
            if (buffer.Contains(" "))
                Console.Write("Этот текст не подходит");
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i++)
                {
                    string word = words[i];
                    if (buffer.Substring(0, 3) == word.Substring(0, 3) && buffer.Substring(buffer.Length - 3) == word.Substring(word.Length - 3))
                    {
                        Clipboard.SetText(word);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

А чтобы не спамить буфер, а читать его только когда он изменился, то надо написать простой класс для отслеживания буфера обмена. Положите его в отдельный файл в проект.

```
public sealed class ClipboardMonitor : IMessageFilter, IDisposable
{
    private const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;
    private bool _disposed;
    private IntPtr _handle;

    /// <summary>
    /// Возникает в случае, если содержимое буфера обмена изменилось.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler ClipboardChanged;

    public ClipboardMonitor(IntPtr handle)
    {
        _handle = handle;
        if (!NativeMethods.AddClipboardFormatListener(_handle))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
                ClipboardChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        if (!NativeMethods.RemoveClipboardFormatListener(_handle))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        _disposed = true;
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
}
```

Далее его не сложно использовать.

Цикл теперь не нужен.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<string> words = new List<string>
    {
        "планета",
        "космос",
        "вселенная",
    };
    private ClipboardMonitor cm;
    private string lastWord;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += Form1_Load;
        FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cm = new ClipboardMonitor(this.Handle);
        cm.ClipboardChanged += cm_ClipboardChanged;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        cm.Dispose();
    }

    private void cm_ClipboardChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            string buffer = Clipboard.GetText().Trim();
            if (buffer == lastWord)
                return;
            if (buffer.Contains(" "))
                Debug.WriteLine("Этот текст не подходит");
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i++)
                {
                    string word = words[i];
                    if (buffer.Substring(0, 3) == word.Substring(0, 3) && buffer.Substring(buffer.Length - 3) == word.Substring(word.Length - 3))
                    {
                        Clipboard.SetText(word);
                        lastWord = word;
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь код будет срабатывать только если в буфере что-то поменялось.

Обратите внимание, что если вы сами что-то записали в буфер, то обработчик будет всё равно вызван, поэтому чтобы не попасть в бесконечный цикл, пришлось добавить проверку.

Comment: А что делать, есть InitializeComponent() красным подчеркивает? Еще плохо во всем разбираюсь

Comment: @kirill321 создайте новый проект Windows Forms, там оно есть и подчеркивать не будет. Я ж не знаю, что вы сделали, что у вас инциализатор формы исчез.

Comment: спасибо, вроде бы все работает) а можно как-то сделать, чтобы программа работала и при закрытом exe файле?

Comment: @kirill321 можно просто спрятать с панели задач, это легко, `this.ShowInTaskBar`, вроде так. Ещё `this.Hide()` есть. Но новые вопросы лучше задавать отдельно.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо!